# Sympy multiplication by 1.0 loses the equality of operator

Tags: sympy

I have what I think it's the most basic problem I have ever encountered:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x

x == 1.0 * x

>> False

x == x * 1.

>> False

x == sympy.Mul(x, 1)

>> False

x == x * 1

>> True
```

While researching about this, I found [sympy's FAQ](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq#why-does-sympy-say-that-two-equal-expressions-are-unequal) and tried all the solutions suggested. `simplify`, `expand`, and I cannot get a True if the multiplication is done by a float `1.0`. Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I found this issue when working with vectors, and the floating `1` comes from an operation that I cannot transform to integer (mathematically it would have no sense).

Comment: Note that sympy wants to find exact symbolic solutions.  Working with imprecise floats should be avoided (when possible, try to use fractions and other mathematical expressions).  Also note that [`==` doesn't test for symbolic equality](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs). This is a consequence of how sympy is integrated into Python. To test for symbolic equality, you can use `Eq(x, x*1.0)`.

Comment: Hm, as I said in my PS, what I was actually doing was something more along the lines of `x == 3 * x / 3.`. However taking out the decimal point in the fraction solved the problem... I still feel this should be an issue, no? Thanks @JohanC

Comment: Well, the 3 issues (`==` not meaning symbolic equality, floats being imprecise and division often unwittingly leading to floats) are all mentioned on sympy's [gotchas and pitfalls page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html). So, yes they are issues, but probably currently not easily to solve.

Comment: You can use `(1.0*x).subs(1.0, 1)` to remove the `1.0`. Otherwise the `1.0` remains there to show that the result is not exact.